# count for loop iteration and do something

Tags: c#

iam looking for a counter there count my iteration in a for loop.

So it should try my function minimum 5 times, and if my function is unsuccessful, it should skip the part after 5 attempts and start the next task.

**How can i count this part and set it to a max lifetime from 5 iterations?**

i tried already to add a Stopwatch but this only counts the time and not the iterations.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    try
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await Task.Delay(100, token);
        lbStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lbStatus.Text = "Search Portal..."));

        float threshold = 0.7f;
        var enemyTemplate =
            new Image<Bgr, byte>(resourceFolder + "/portalenter.png");
        var enemyMask =
            new Image<Bgr, byte>(resourceFolder + "/portalentermask.png");

        Point myPosition = new Point(150, 128);
        Point screenResolution = new Point(1920, 1080);

        // Main program loop
        var enemyDetector = new EnemyDetector(enemyTemplate, enemyMask, threshold);
        var screenPrinter = new PrintScreen();

        screenPrinter.CaptureScreenToFile("screen.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        var screenCapture = new Image<Bgr, byte>("screen.png");
        var enemy = enemyDetector.GetClosestEnemy(screenCapture);
        if (enemy.HasValue)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(100, token);
            CvInvoke.Rectangle(screenCapture,
                new Rectangle(new Point(enemy.Value.X, enemy.Value.Y), enemyTemplate.Size),
                new MCvScalar(255));
            var inputSimulator = new InputSimulator();
            double x1 = 963f / myPosition.X;
            double y1 = 551f / myPosition.Y;
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(100, token);
            var x2 = x1 * enemy.Value.X;
            var y2 = y1 * enemy.Value.Y;
            if (x2 <= 963)
                x2 = x2 * 0.68f;
            else
                x2 = x2 * 1.38f;
            if (y2 <= 551)
                y2 = y2 * 0.68;
            else
                y2 = y2 * 1.38;
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(100, token);
            var absolutePositions = PixelToAbsolute(x2, y2, screenResolution);
            inputSimulator.Mouse.MoveMouseTo(absolutePositions.Item1, absolutePositions.Item2);
            au3.Send("{G}");
            if (txtLEFT.Text == "LEFT")
            {
                inputSimulator.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
            }
            else
            {
                inputSimulator.Mouse.RightButtonClick();
            }

            au3.Send("{G}");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (txtLEFT.Text == "LEFT")
            {
                inputSimulator.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
            }
            else
            {
                inputSimulator.Mouse.RightButtonClick();
            }

            au3.Send("{G}");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(100, token);
        }
        else
        {
            /// DO SOMETHING AFTER 5 iterations
            cts.Cancel();
            lbStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lbStatus.Text = "Portal not found! Restart..."));

            var t13 = Task.Run(() => Exit2(token));
            await Task.WhenAny(new[] { t13 });
        }
    }
    catch (AggregateException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Expected");
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bug");
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the `for` loop?

Comment: post is edited.

Comment: How do you know it's been unsuccessful? I can see a `try` but no `catch`, an `else` but no `if`. Have you considered setting some flag if successful, breaking out of the loop, then running the `// DO SOMETHING AFTER 5 iterations` code if that flag hasn't been set?

Comment: its already edited catch is on bottom

Comment: I am not 100% sure about correctness of you exception usage.

Comment: my exception is for a cancellation token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to run some code and if it fails, retry, but max. 5 times? You can do it this way:

```
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    try {
        doSomething();
        break; // Break if successful.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Print the exception, etc.
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Delay the next iteration.

        // Optional: Rethrow if it is the last iteration.
        if (i == 0) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

You can replace the `doSomething();` line with the actual code or call a (private) method that performs that operation. The latter is usually preferred, since you separate the looping construct from the actual code.

Note that the break is placed after the work. Therefore, if the `doSomething()` fails, it skips the `break;` line and goes directly to the catch (and then to the next iteration). If it succeeds, it breaks out from the loop.

Comment: 5 attempts should be forced and if the last one was unsuccessful then something else should be done

Comment: The code in the answer tries running the code 5 times and ends the loop only in two cases: ① when exception is thrown on the fifth iteration or ② any iteration is successful (non-throwing). Do you want to do that?

Comment: no it should run the code min. 5 times. i forgot to explain this better, sorry

Comment: Run 5 times (even if that fails) and then run until it starts failing?

Comment: its correct. it can also be successful and still fail because my player didn't get to exactly the right spot. So after the 5 attempts, no matter what the result, I need a catch function that says Start Task Restart and try again. I want to prevent players from getting stuck. maybe you have to know, that if all was succesfull, the player interact with a portal and click a button to teleport to next station. there is enough space between the next stage. but if the player get stuck in the stage before, he have to wait 5 minutes until my program Restarts

Answer (score 0):

I'll ignore most of your code as I'm not sure it's relevant to the problem. You're running something 5 times using a for loop.

I'd suggest you set a flag if it's successful and then check after that loop has completed as to whether you need to run your compensating action:

```cs
var success = false;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    try
    { 
        // your code here
        // if completed, set success and break out of loop
        success = true;
        break;
    }
    catch 
    { 
        // your error handling here
    }
}

if (success == false)
{
    // this code executes if action failed after 5 attempts
}
```

Comment: This comes the solution closer, but its important that my code should have these 5 trys. i dont want to set a bool success, because my OpenCV search for a small icon, then it calculate the difference between me and the portal and then walk to them. and this is not everytime succesfull, because sometimes the player walk a little bit besides and cannot reach the interact Button. So i need min. 5 iterations, sorry that i did not have explain this well in my first post. what would be possible would be to set a bool after reaching the fifth try

Comment: @StevenLippert Ok - in which case, how do you know whether it's failed? What will have happened after 5 iterations that lets you decide if it's succeeded or not? I had assumed that throwing an exception meant it had failed, but it sounds like that's not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a while loop instead.
Increase a counter if it failed and then exit if successful or failed too many times

```
int n = 0;
bool success = false;

do
{
    //Do something
    if(failed)
    {
        n++;
    }
    else
    {
        success = true;
    }
} while (n < 5 || !success);
```

Comment: Isn't that just less readable way to write `for` loop?

Comment: Question of taste and coding standards I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if statement for anything before 5 iterations and then the other after the fifth iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
     try {
          if (i < 5) {
              // DO EVERYTHING YOU WANT BEFORE 5 ITERATIONS
          } else {
              // DO EVERYTHING AFTER 5
          }
     }
     catch { }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. it just ignores the else{ } it tries 5 times and then just moves on to the next task.